# Ответ на пост-запрос

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, post

Есть сервер, который должен отвечать на Post-запрос от API. Сервер устанавливается через ngrok.

```
IPEndPoint ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);
 
Socket listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
try
{
    listenSocket.Bind(ipPoint);     
    listenSocket.Listen(10); 
    Console.WriteLine("Server is starting...");
 
    while (true)
    {
        Socket handler = listenSocket.Accept();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int bytes = 0; 
        byte[] data = new byte[256]; 
 
        do
        {
            bytes = handler.Receive(data);
            builder.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
        }
        while (handler.Available > 0);
 
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ": " + builder.ToString());
 
        string message = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK";
        data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        handler.Send(data);
        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        handler.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

API - telegram-bot. В моём случае, я просто пишу сообщение боту и он отсылает мне json'овский файл в виде строки со всей необходимой инфой. Но, проблема в том, что Телеграм на мой сервер отсылает бесконечное количество Post-запросов, на которые я не знаю как ответить. Как мне реализовать эту возможность - ответа на post-запрос?

Comment: You should better post your question on https://stackoverflow.com/, not the russian one.

Comment: simply translate your question and try to get answer here

Comment: @AzizUmarov Could you be more specific?

Comment: translate on Russion. this is RU.STACKOVERFLOW.COM

Comment: @AzizUmarov Спасибо за поправку! Не разобрался поначалу

Comment: Просто не могу не посоветовать уже изобретенный велосипед - [ASP.NET Core Web API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: @aepot А без ASP.NET'а никак? Я просто не знаю как в ASP.Net'е сделать чисто сервер без представлений, читал, что это нецелесообразно. К тому же моё приложение меня устраивает, не хватает только работы с POST-запросами

Comment: ASP.NET сервер - уже готовое решение, в которое можно просто накидать нужных маршрутов и тратить время только на написание кода, пережевывающего готовые данные. Всю остальную низкоуровневую техническую работу сервер сделает сам. К тому же, Core есть поддержка всяких TLS и HTTP/2. Конечно же, вы можете сами реализовать свой HTTP, но с каждой новой потребностью код сервера будет расти, и большая часть этого кода будет отвечать именно за низкий сетевой уровень. К тому же, ASP.NET Core относительно защищен от атак извне, и код его поддерживается в акутальном состоянии. Решать конечно же вам.

Comment: Но если очень хочется, то вот, [копать туда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8637871/12888024)

Comment: `HTTP/1.0` - если уж вы решили сами, то я вам настоятельно рекомендую пользоваться как минимум спецификацией `1.1`, потому что `1.0` уже устарел и почти не поддерживается Ынтернетом. Даже если удалось установить соединение и пообщаться с другим сервером в рамках `1.0`, то все равно не факт, что не возникнет всякого рода сюрпризов, связанных с тем, что удаленный сервер (или клиент) не поддерживает `1.0` в полной мере.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо за ответ, попробую пока без ASP.net. В дальнейшем же опробую и его, однако пока не могу найти нормальной документации, где описывалось бы как загрузить сервер. Что я имею ввиду: 
1. Не понятно как мне проект ASP.net привязать к серверу, запущенному через ngrok
2. Покажусь очень несмышленым, но во всех руководствах относительно ASP.net я сталкивался с представлениями - что мне, по сути, не нужно. Может, есть ссылка на руководство чистого сервера на ASP.net?

Comment: @aepot Кстати, по поводу [этого примера](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637856/httplistener-with-post-data/8637871#8637871). Там же вроде как вопрос был именно в получении данных из POST-Запроса, что я делаю в своём проекте, а мне нужно как бы подтвердить, что я эти данные получил(я не знаю как это делать вообще).